# RTSP Streaming for web server

Tags: ios4, video-streaming, rtsp

Last few days I am working hard on RTSP streaming directly on iPhone but could not got any solution. Today i came up with another question that, whetherit is possible to stream "rtsp://urlString/filename.sdp" to an http server and then from http to iphone.

If it is the way how will it work?

Please, do suggest me something for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked a lot on RTSP streaming but could not get any solution. Rather I got to know that RTSP streaming is not supported by iPhone directly.

Their are few private libraries available but those are not approved by apple.

So the simple answer is RTSP streaming is not directly supported by iPhone till today, may be it would be available in later versions of iPhone sdk.